# Navigation to a view but occurred Exception Region with the given name is already registered

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a WPF project with Prism 6.

I have a view (TitleSearchView) that used a region:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TitleTreeRegion"/>
    <Button Content="View" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" MinWidth="80" Command="{Binding TitleViewCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

And I have a Menu Item that I want to open "TitleSearchView" , I used from  Navigation :

```
    var parameters = new NavigationParameters { { "viewMode", viewMode } };
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionsName.ContentRegion, ViewsName.TitleSearchView, parameters);
```

And "TitleSearchViewModel" implement "INavigationAware":

```
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        ViewMode = (ViewModeEnum)navigationContext.Parameters["viewMode"];
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {

    }
```

Now when I Click on the menu item for the first time, this is OK But after that, if click on menu item occurred The Application IS In Break Mode:

I guess this happening for this exception:

"Region with the given name is already registered"

I register this region in "TitleModule":

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.TitleTreeRegion, typeof(TitleTreeView));
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried: Debug > Windows> Exception Settings (Ctrl + Alt + E): Check Common Language Runtime Exceptions ?

Comment: Hi Nawed, I didn't use Exception Settings until now.
do you have a reference for me?
what do I do?

Comment: Make sure Common Language Runtime Exceptions are checked, that when you will get notified when an exception occurs. Once you know the exception you also know what to do about it.

Comment: I checked Common Language Runtime Exceptions but occurred The Application IS In Break Mode again.

Comment: Then Click Continue execution... Most likely your exception is occurring in an external DLL

Comment: I Clicked on Continue execution... But debugging was stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolve my problem.

There is the exception "Region with the given name is already registered".

When we navigate to a "View" that included a "Region", this region add to "RegionCollection" in "NavigationService", if more one time add the region to the RegionCollection, the exception occurred.

So we should:

```
    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.RegionManager.Regions.Remove(RegionNames.TitleTreeRegion);
    }
```